# Java Service Wrapper: socket not open, so packet not sent SERVICE_CONTROL_CODE : 4

Tags: java, windows-services, java-service-wrapper

We're using Java Service Wrapper and something weird is going on: I get the following lines repeated in the wrapper log file until someone manualy kills the process tree.

```
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2010/10/13 11:57:10 | socket not open, so packet not sent     SERVICE_CONTROL_CODE : 4
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2010/10/13 11:57:10 | ServiceControlHandler(4)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2010/10/13 11:57:10 |   SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ServiceControlHandler(4)" and "SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE" messages are saying that the Windows Service Manager is pinging the service to see if it is still alive.  This is normal on some systems that have monitoring software active.  How often are you getting them? They do not originate from the Wrapper itself.

The "socket not open..." message is saying that the socket between the Wrapper and JVM is not open.  Most likely this is because the JVM is not running in the current state.

I would need to see more of your wrapper.log as well as your wrapper.conf file to tell you why the JVM socket is not open at the moment.

Also what version of the Wrapper are you using?

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: thanks for the response Lief, but i have re-arranged everything since I wrote this question and it is no longer a problem. I couldn't tell you how I fixed it, it just stopped happening.